# How can I edit existing activerecord objects in a sql database using ruby scripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-import

How can activerecord objects be edited externally with scripts? I'm currently using the `activerecord-import` gem to insert objects into the database. Is it possible to edit existing records using this gem or using another tool or gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit unspecific. There are quite a few methods. Here's the best:

You can run rails on the console. Try `irb` in your project's directory, and you're on a REPL that allows you to run code live. Just try something like:

```
that_guy = User.find(4)
that_guy.name = "John"
that_guy.save!
```

(Replace `User`, `4` and `name` with a model you have, a record's id and some string attribute).

And of course you can also just run a file of ruby against your project: `rails runner your_script.rb`

And, if I misunderstood you: you can of course access the database through any other means/languages/libraries.

Comment: You have all the ActiveRecord finder methods at your disposal so `find_by(name: 'Bob')` also works. `rails runner` or a `rake` task is a good plan for these utility scripts.